# Calculating the residues of $f(z)=\frac{ze^{iaz}}{z^4+4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have $f(z)=\frac{ze^{iaz}}{z^4+4}$. The poles of $f$ are {$\pm1\pm i$}.

How do I calculate $2\pi i \sum \operatorname{Res}\limits_{z = \pm 1 + i} f(z)$ ? (I'm only looking at positive $i$'s.)

I've tried using the property $\operatorname{Res}f(z) = \frac1{g'(p)}$ and that gives me $\frac1 4 e^{ia(\pm1+i)}$. But then I realised the property only works for one pole. How do I do this?

Comment: If $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ where $g,h$ are holomorphic, $h$ has a zero of order $1$ at a point $a$ and $g(a)\ne 0$ then $Res_f(a)=\frac{g(a)}{h'(a)}$. In your case this formula works.

Comment: When the poles are simple, you can calculate $Res_{z=z_0}f(z)= \frac{\xi'(z_0)}{\varphi'(z_0)}$ where $\xi$ is the function on the numerator and $\varphi$ is the function on the denominator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By l'Hôpital's rule, the residue is$$\begin{align}\lim_{z\to\pm1+i}\frac{z-(\pm1+i)}{(z^3+4z^{-1})e^{-iaz}}&=\lim_{z\to\pm1+i}\frac{1}{(-iaz^3-4iaz^{-1}+3z^2-4z^{-2})e^{-iaz}}\\&=\frac{e^{-a\pm ia}}{-ia(\pm1+i)^3-4ia(\pm1+i)^{-1}+3(\pm1+i)^2-4(\pm1+i)^{-2}},\end{align}$$which I leave you to simplify further using e.g. $(\pm1+i)^{-1}=(\pm1-i)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for instance, the residue at $1+i$. Since$$z^4+4=(z-1-i)(1-1+i)(z+1-i)(z+1+i),$$define$$g(z)=\frac{ze^{iaz}}{(z-1+i)(z+1-i)(z+1+i)},$$and you have $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z-1-i}$. Therefore,\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=1+i}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)&=\operatorname{res}_{z=1+i}\left(\frac{g(z)}{z-1-i}\right)\\&=g(1+i)\\&=-\frac{ie^{(-1+i)a}}8.\end{align}